# Is it safe to use std::bind on an uninitialized object?

Tags: c++, bind

Due to my inability to properly design my classes I reached a point where I need something like this:

```
struct A
{
   A( function< void(string&) cb > ): callback(cb) {}
   function< void(string&) > callback;

   template <std::size_t T>
   void func( string& str) { ... }
}

int main(){
vector<A> items = {
   A( bind( &A::func<1>, items[0], _1) ),
   A( bind( &A::func<2>, items[1], _1) ),
   ...
}
```

Is this safe to use? If not, is there an alternative?

Comment: So...what is the problem you're trying to solve where this is your solution?

Comment: The main problem you have already detected: *inability to properly design*. You need to work on that, rather than hack a solution. As @GManNickG already mentioned, if you provide the **problem** that you are trying to solve, you might get answers that offer better designs. There are different ways of making this work, but that won't make the design any better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is certainly not safe. The `items[0]` is going to be evaluated before `items` is initialized.

The proper thing to do here is probably to just use a lambda, like

```
vector<A> items = {
    A( [&items](string& s){ items[0].func(s); } ),
    A( [&items](string& s){ items[1].func(s); } ),
    ...
}
```

This only grabs a reference to `items` during the initialization, and then pulls out `items[0]` only when the callback is actually called.

Alternatively, could you change the callback to take the `A&` as a parameter? If your callback type is `std::function<void(A&, string&)>` then you can just pass `&A::func<1>` as the callback and it will work.

Answer (score 5):

You're using the `[]` operator to access the `vector` before it's constructed. This isn't safe.

I think you're going to have to create non-fully initialized items in the `vector` and then set the bindee later.

Answer (score 0):

The code in `main` creates a fixed-size vector. If that's actually what's required, use an array or an `std::array`, and pass the **address** of the element to the `bind` call:

```
A items[] = {
   A( bind( &A::func<1>, &items[0], _1) ),
   A( bind( &A::func<2>, &items[1], _1) ),
   ...
};
```

The function object returned by `bind` knows how to bind a pointer-to-object and a member function.